# Select multiple items across multiple tables with join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-4.0

Trying to convert a SQL query to LINQ (as I have added code to download the 2 SQL tables and save them to a DataSet in memory).  Therefore, I need the LINQ to be selecting the same stuff as the SQL was.

SQL Query

```
SELECT s.item1, s.item2, l.itemA, l.itemB
FROM table1 s, table2 l
WHERE l.itemA = name AND s.item1 = l.itemB
```

What I have so far that doesn't compile (DBConfig is a DataSet with multiple tables)

```
var query = from l in DbConfig.Tables["table2"].AsEnumerable()
            join s in DbConfig.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable() on l.Field<string>("itemB") equals s.Field<string>("item1")
            where l.Field<string>("itemA") == name
            select s.item, s.item2, l.itemA, l.itemB;
```

I'm very new to LINQ so any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that when you call `AsEnumerable` the query must be executed on the client, rather than on the SQL server. I'd **strongly** recommend leaving the tables as `IQueryable`'s to avoid this.

Next, as [*Tim S.* explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337429/1715579), since your tables are not strongly typed, use the `Field<T>` method to retrieve the column value.

Finally, if you want to return multiple columns, you'll need to group the results into an anonymous type:

```
var query = from l in DbConfig.Tables["table2"]
            join s in DbConfig.Tables["table1"]
            on l.Field<string>("itemB") equals s.Field<string>("item1")
            where l.Field<string>("itemA") == name
            select new { 
                item = s.Field<string>("item"), 
                item2 = s.Field<string>("item2"), 
                itemA = l.Field<string>("itemA"), 
                itemB = l.Field<string>("itemB") 
            };
```

Or create a named type to represent the results:

```
public class MyResultType {
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string item2 { get; set; }
    public string itemA { get; set; }
    public string itemB { get; set; }
}

var query = from l in DbConfig.Tables["table2"]
            join s in DbConfig.Tables["table1"] 
            on l.Field<string>("itemB") equals s.Field<string>("item1")
            where l.Field<string>("itemA") == name
            select new MyResultType { 
                item = s.Field<string>("item"), 
                item2 = s.Field<string>("item2"), 
                itemA = l.Field<string>("itemA"), 
                itemB = l.Field<string>("itemB") 
            };
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it says that "DataRow does not contain a definition for 'itemx'" and so on.  When I try the select this way: `select new { servers.Field<string>("servername"), servers.Field<string>("ip") };` it says "An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name".  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Hershizer33 In that case you'd have to specify the name: `select new { servername = servers.Field<string>("servername"), ip = servers.Field<string>("ip") };` -- see [**Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

Comment: Seems to be working... last question, how can I change the `query` into a DataTable? Seems like I can do it buy creating a DataTable, adding the columns, and foreaching through `query` but I feel like there has to be a better way...

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not dealing with strongly typed results, you can't select the results with, e.g., `s.item1`; you have to use `Field<>` (or something similar), like in the rest of your query. Also, since you can only select one object in a LINQ query, and you want four values, you should either select them in a new anonymous type, or create a type to store them.

```
var query = from l in DbConfig.Tables["table2"].AsEnumerable()
            join s in DbConfig.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
              on l.Field<string>("itemB") equals s.Field<string>("item1")
            where l.Field<string>("itemA") == name
            select
      new { Item1 = s.Field<string>("item1"), Item2 = s.Field<string>("item2"),
            ItemA = l.Field<string>("itemA"), ItemB = l.Field<string>("itemB") };
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
var data=from dr1 in DbConfig.Tables["table2"].AsEnumerable()
      join dr2 in DbConfig.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
        on dr1.Field<string>("itemB") equals  dr2.Field<string>("item1")
      where dr1.Field<string>("itemA") == name
      select new {item = dr2.Field<string>("item"), 
                item2 = dr2.Field<string>("item2"), 
                itemA = dr1.Field<string>("itemA"), 
                itemB = dr1.Field<string>("itemB") }
```

Always use named types (custom classes ) instead of anonymous types for maintainability and extensibility.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes you are correct. My query is not correct I missed the other join condition. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see the lambda syntax

```
var query = DbConfig.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
            .Join
            (
                DbConfig.Tables["table2"].AsEnumerable(),
                x=>x.Field<string>("item1"),
                x=>x.Field<string>("itemB"),
                (t1,t2)=>new {t1,t2}
            )
            .Where
            (
                x=>x.t2.Field<string>("itemA") == name
            )
            .Select
            (
                x=>
                new
                {
                    x.t1.Field<string>("item"), 
                    x.t1.Field<string>("item2"), 
                    x.t2.Field<string>("itemA"), 
                    x.t2.Field<string>("itemB")
                }
            )
```